# Using curl to send xml data

Tags: http, unix, curl, terminal

I'm trying to do a propfind with curl.  I can get it to work provided I type all of my data on the same line (no newlines) and escape () any quotation marks. What I would like to do is specify my data to send in a text file or something so I can type it out in some legible way and then have curl use it.

I know curl can read from a file like this:

```
curl --user username:password --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --request PROPFIND https://whatevermyurlis.com --data-urlencode @blah.txt
```

but I keep getting Bad Request back.  Document is empty, line 1, column 1

Comment: So the same exact line works when you replace `@blah.txt` with a plain xml string?

Comment: Yes it does, provided I take out all newlines and " (and I don't use url encode then either)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't like text files...I changed it to .xml and it worked fine.

Comment: Interesting.  I assumed since you said it works using a plain xml string that your file `blah.txt` actually included the same xml.  Are you saying you had to change the file extension to `.txt` in order to make it work?  That seems odd to me; I would think curl would just take the input from the file, interpret it according to your Content-type header and you would be good do go.

Comment: I read the answer to mean that JPC changed the file name from ``blah.txt`` to ``blah.xml``